# Android GCM and cloud services

Tags: google-cloud-messaging, android

I have a gaming App in android launched in Google play. I would like to update the user score somewhere in cloud and make it available across the users. Is there is any free service by Google for the App Publishers. Can we use GCM for this purpose.

Any pointers / Ideas on this will be highly appreciated.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can use gcm or cloud connect for this purpose, may be this links are helpful to you

http://developer.android.com/training/cloudsync/gcm.html

https://bradablog.appspot.com/?p=207

if you wants to leaderboard check this link:

https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/leaderboards